# use of unsigned char pointer

Tags: c

I have a pattern

and I have byte stream and I need to find how many occurrences of this byte is present in my byte stream. The pattern can be found at any bit position.

Comment: Is bit pattern always a single byte?

Comment: What have you yet tried ? You should read about bitwise operators: <<, >>, &, |, ^, ~, ....

Comment: Do leading zeros count? For example, If my pattern is `0x05` and my stream is `00, 00, A5, 00, 00`, is the answer 1 or 2?

Comment: the pattern is always 1 byte

Comment: Read byte A. (x) Check byte A for the pattern. If byte B is "empty" read in a byte to byte B. Shift a bit out of byte B into byte A. Repeat from (x).

Comment: The answer would be 0, there is a no match

Comment: @Invictus my algorithm tests every run of 8 bits, in overlapping bytes, at bit 0, bit 1, bit 2, ...

Comment: Can you give a small snippet of what are you doing?

Answer (score 1):

This works by reading the file one byte at a time and rotating bits into a test variable. You could modify it to read from a string (unwilling to give you "pat" code).

```
#include <stdio.h>

size_t count_patt(char *filename, unsigned char pattern)
{
    size_t count = 0;
    int byteA, byteB, bits = 0;
    FILE *fp;
    if((fp = fopen(filename, "rb")) == NULL) {
        return count;
    }
    if((byteA = fgetc(fp)) == EOF) {
        return count;
    }
    while(1) {
        if(byteA == pattern) {
            count++;
        }
        if(bits <= 0) {
            if((byteB = fgetc(fp)) == EOF)          // refresh byte B
                break;
            bits = 8;                               // which has 8 bits
        }
        byteA = (byteA << 1) & 0xFF;                // rotate byte A left
        if((byteB & 0x80) != 0) {
            byteA++;                                // shift in ms bit of byte B
        }
        byteB <<= 1;                                // rotate byte B left
        bits--;                                     // bit tally
    }
    return count;
}

int main()
{
    printf("%zu bytes\n", count_patt("test.txt", 0x31));
}
```

Contents of test.txt (2 bytes 01000010 01100011)

```
Bc
```

Program output

```
1 bytes
```

Comment: It will work on any length data up to the limit of `size_t` type. I am getting 8 bits from file at a time, and storing them in `int` because that's the return type of `fgetc`. I then shift 1 bit (of 8) at a time into the test variable. There is no reason why you can't read each value from a character array instead of from a file. I am not going to write the exact code you need, as stated in the answer, this is to give you an idea how to go about it. PS sorry I forgot to close the file.

Comment: Notice that I am only using the least significant 8 bits of `byteA` with the mask `0xFF`, and notice how I always extract bit 7 of `byteB` with the mask `0x80`, to move into bit 0 of `byteA`. That woould be the same if I was using `unsigned char` - it makes no difference to the algorithm.

Comment: By copying it to an `int` then manipulate it like I did. An `unsigned char` can be promoted safely to `int` because `int` can hold all the possible values of `unsigned char`. Instead of reading a byte from file, read it from your string.

Comment: In that case over to you: ask a new question with the code you have tried, the input you gave, the output you expected and the output you got. This is not a code writing service. I just gave you some ideas.